# paste text to bluetooth?

Tags: applications, bluetooth

I'm using the PasswordSafe app and am looking for an easy way to send passwords from my phone to other computers. I can copy the password to the clipboard but what then? *Is there an app that will have the phone claim to be a Bluetooth keyboard and 'type' whatever is on the clipboard?*

Comment: I don't know of anything like this but you could opt to use a cloud based password program like lastpass that would keep you passwords synced with a lot less work.

Comment: @Matt: That would solve one problem, but it's not this one.

Answer (score -1):

It uses WiFi, rather than Bluetooth, but other than that it sounds like you could use an app like [ShareText](http://www.appbrain.com/app/sharetext-free/com.domobile.sharetextfree)?

From ShareText's description:

> Share text with wifi on pc or other
> device using your Browser.
>
> Copy/paste between phone and pc. You can copy the
> text from pc to phone, from phone to pc,
> from this phone to another phone, from
> phone to any browser.